# Making tinyMCE and Garlic.js work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I'm trying to make Garlic.js and tinyMCE work together in my Rails app without success. I've integrated Garlic in my asset pipeline and for tinyMCE I'm using tinymce-rails gem.

Both work great separately but when I put them together Garlic stops working.

I've recently tried micschk's potential solution posted in Garlic's github repository https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Garlic.js/issues/87 which involves initialising tinymce with the following code:

**views/layouts/application.html (following script inside head tag)**

```
<script>
  tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
    setup : function(editor) {
      editor.on("change keyup", function(e){
        console.log('saving');
        tinyMCE.triggerSave(); // updates all instances
        // editor.save(); // updates this instance's textarea
        $(editor.getElement()).trigger('change'); // for garlic to detect change
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

the code does initialise tinymce and runs the code after 'setup' but it does not seem to make Garlic work.

**Here's my view code for reference**

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@open_ender, remote: true, html: {"data-persist" => 'garlic', id:'open_ender_form' }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.input :answer_id, :required => true, :as => :hidden, :autofocus => true, input_html: {value: @answer.id } %>
            <%= f.input :content, :input_html => { :class => 'tinymce' }, :label => false, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
            <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', id: "save-btn", style:'background:transparent' ) do %>
                <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true" title="save"; data-toggle="tooltip"; data-placement="right"></i>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally decided to use the tinyMCE autosave plug-in instead of using Garlic.js although the functionality is not exactly the same it serves the purpose of protecting users from losing their data.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/autosave/